# SQL syntax error:1064, how to fix it?

Tags: python, mysql, twisted

I wrote a Udp server by python(Twisted), receive udp message and update mysql database:

```
sql = "update `device` set `msg`='%s', `d_addr`='%s', `d_port`=%d where `did`=%d" %(msg, host, port, r[0])
try:
    txn.execute(sql)
except Exception, e:
    f = open('./err_log', 'a')
    f.write('%s\n' % e)
    f.write('%s\n' % sql)
    f.close()
```

error info in err_log is:

```
(1064, "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '220.168.13.132', `d_port`=14058 where `did`=2' at line 1")

update `device` set `msg`='.?F/.ddd?', `d_addr`='220.168.13.132', `d_port`=14058 where `did`=2
```

so, I executed the sql manually, but there was not error:

```
MariaDB [kj]> update `device` set `msg`='.?F/.ddd?',
    `d_addr`='220.168.13.132', `d_port`=14058 where `did`=2;
Query OK, 1 row affected (0.00 sec)
Rows matched: 1  Changed: 1  Warnings: 0
```

the msg is string(18 bytes) sent by remote client, the ascii code of string is:

```
0x86 0xAC 0xCF 0x23 0x29 ... 0xE3
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Parameterize the query* and forget about SQL syntax errors related to inserting variables into the query. As a bonus, you are making your code safe from [SQL injection attacks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection):

```
sql = """
    UPDATE
        device 
    SET 
        msg = %s, 
        d_addr = %s, 
        d_port = %s 
    where 
        did = %s"""
txn.execute(sql, (msg, host, port, r[0]))
```

Comment: @liuhui if you parameterize the query - the driver would automatically detect the types and handle type conversions. Have you tried the code provided in the answer?

Comment: However, I don't know why the sql syntax error occur